# Add resize event when window changes from mobile to desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window

everyone!

I was just wondering if anyone might be able to fill me in on how to add a resize event to the following code:

```
    /* Your code goes here */ 

var $ = jQuery,
breakpoint = 940,
initClass = 'toggleSubnavInitiated',
menu,
parentLinks,
childrenItems;

$(document).ready(function() {
menu = $('.menu');
parentLinks = menu.find('.menu-item-has-children > a');
childrenItems = menu.find('.sub-menu');

if ($(window).width() <= breakpoint) {
    toggleSubnav(menu, parentLinks, childrenItems);
}
});

$(window).resize(function() {

if ($(window).width() <= breakpoint) {
    toggleSubnav(menu, parentLinks, childrenItems);
}
});

function toggleSubnav(menu, parentLinks, childrenItems) {

if (parentLinks.length !== 0) {
    menu.addClass(initClass);
    childrenItems.hide();

    parentLinks.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggle();
    });
}
}
```

It looks like there is one in this block of code, but it doesn't seem to resize when the browser shifts from mobile site to desktop site. On Chrome, I was able to get 941 px as the breakpoint where the switch happens from mobile to desktop. 940 px, which I guess is included in this script, is from desktop to mobile? Desktop to mobile seems to function properly. Anyone have any ideas on how to add a resize event when the window goes from mobile to desktop at 941 px?

Thanks, everyone, for your help!

P.S. I just joined here, so go easy on me, please! ;)

Comment: you have a legitimate resize() event assigned to the window. what is your problem in this code? When you switch from desktop to mobile, how you do it? using Chrome web developer tools?

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is... Your resize event and callback look like they are properly defined.
Does your code work when you're using Chrome?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the comment. I realized it was confusing. What I noticed the problem was was that when the window went from mobile site to desktop site, it didn't refresh the page automatically. The breakpoint from mobile site to desktop site is 941px. The resize event for 940 px seems necessary to go from desktop to mobile. I guess I'm just missing another resize event to go from mobile to desktop (i.e. 941 px)?

Comment: else condition in resize function

Comment: and what might that look like? This code was given to me by someone, and I'm not too sure how to incorporate an else function into this

Answer (score 0):

Your `resize()` event is properly set when you go from a value higher than 940px to one lower. However, you haven't defined any behavior for going the other way around. You can modify your code this way:

```
/* your previous code */
$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() <= breakpoint) {
        toggleSubnav(menu, parentLinks, childrenItems);
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggle(); //I assume you want the menu to disappear when moving back to a wider screen
    }
});
```

I would be careful also using the `toggle()` method because each time it is called, it will either show or hide your menu. So imagine the user resizes a first time under 940px, the menu will show as you planned. If he resizes even lower, your menu will disappear again.

Comment: Thanks for your super fast reply. I really appreciate it. When I add that to the script and test it, on the mobile site, the child menus auto-expand from the their parent menus. The code above was to help auto-collapse all child menu items into its parent ones.

Comment: You can try `toggle(display)`, `display` being a boolean. Set it to `true` to show the menu, `false` to hide them.

Comment: So something like:

'$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() <= breakpoint) {
        toggleSubnav(menu, parentLinks, childrenItems);
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggle(display(true)); //I assume you want the menu to disappear when moving back to a wider screen
    }
});
'
I tried that, but no luck :(

Comment: When you tried that, what was the behavior you obtained? Did you also change to `toggle(false)` in the `toggleSubnav` method?

Comment: So, it works as if I didn't add the additional piece of code. Is there a code I can add that just says if the window is <941px and becomes 941px or larger, to refresh the page?